# Mysql Select all Rows after nth Position

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I wish to fetch all rows from table after the nth Position as i given offset value
my table like

```
id | Value
1  | A |
2  | B |
3  | C |
4  | D |
5  | E |

...

N  | R |
```

I wants the 3rd row Data to Nth Rows How to i Retrive

Comment: @akina how to i fix this

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @Lennart Mysql 5.0 and above

Comment: 8 is a lot more powerfull than 5, but then the solution must work for 5?

Comment: @Lennart yes i know that but live server codes are maintained version 5 standard so  i'm unable to update the server version right now

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, the oldest version I could test was 5.6

```
select t1.id, t1.val 
from t t1
left join (
   select t2.id from t t2 order by id limit 2
) x
on t1.id = x.id
where x.id is null;
```

For 8.0, a window function is the most natural choice

```
select id, val from (
  select id, val
     , row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from t
) as x 
where rn > 2
```

As [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) pointed out in a comment, LIMIT in combination with OFFSET can also be used. For a trivial case with only one partition, it is likely the most efficient solution:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val 
FROM t t1
LIMIT 1000000000000 OFFSET 2
```

Comment: I wasn't searching hard enough: [MySQL 5.0 : SELECT syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/sql-syntax.html#select)